# Issue with cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery and cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery with data types and field order

Tags: json, marklogic

I have MarkLogic 9 on my database.

I have created the following documents in my database:

```
test1.json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": "A", 
            "value": 0
        }
    ]
}

test2.json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": "A", 
            "value": "0"
        }
    ]
}

test3.json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "value": 0, 
            "userId": "A"
        }
    ]
}

test4.json
{
    "users": [
        {
            "value": "0", 
            "userId": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have run the following codes and have recorded the results:

```
cts.uris(“”, null, cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery(
    "users",
    cts.andQuery(
        [
            cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('userId', "A"),
            cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('value', "0"),
        ]
    )   
))
```

Result: test2.json, test4.json

```
cts.uris(“”, null, cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery(
    "users",
    cts.andQuery(
        [
            cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('userId', "A"),
            cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('value', 0),
        ]
    )   
))
```

Result: test3.json

I was wondering why test1.json did not return in the 2nd query while test3.json did. They both had the same values for fields but in different order. The order of the fields are different in test2.json and test4.json, however, the query returned both documents. The only difference between the 2 pairs that I can think of is that there are 2 data types for the field “value”, integer and string.

How would I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery shows the value to match as an array.

If you want to keep the variants in data, maybe you can try something on the query side like cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('value', ["0", 0])

Comment: I have tried the following code, and documents 'test2.json', 'test3.json', and 'test4.json' were returned.  
I am able to keep the variants in data, but I am still unable to retrieve document 'test1.json'.  
`cts.uris(“”, null, cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery(
    "users",
    cts.andQuery(
  [
   cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('userId', "A"),
   cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery('value', [0, "0"]),
  ]
 ) 
))`

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what's going on.  Works for me on default database settings in 9.0-9 and 10.0-2.1.